# Mount VHD and get drive letter

Tags: powershell

I am looking to get the drive letter of the VHD mount using Powershell. I can mount the VHD with the below cmdlet:

```
Mount-VHD -Path d:/tmp.vhdx
```

The mount works fine, but when I try getting the drive letter:

```
Get-DiskImage -ImagePath d:\tmp.vhdx | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume ).DriveLetter
```

It fails with below error:

> Get-DiskImage : Invalid property

I believe `Get-DiskImage` works fine for an ISO, but not for VHD? Can you help me in obtaining it for VHD.

Comment: `$Volumes = Mount-VHD -Path d:\temp.vhdx -PassThru | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume` [See the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/mount-vhd?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 6):

This way work for me:

```
$DriveLetter = (Mount-VHD -Path "G:\YourVHDX.vhdx" -PassThru | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

Then `Write-Output $DriveLetter` will show the drive letter.

Comment: For me this works sometimes, but many times I get an empty letter as if it was not yet assigned.  Not sure what to do to...

Answer (score 0):

```
$DriveLetter = (Mount-VHD -Path "G:\YourVHDX.vhdx" -PassThru | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemLabel -like ""}).DriveLetter
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on windows 10. `Write-Output $DriveLetter` just shows nothing.