# How to mount a VHD and then get its letter in two different steps?

Tags: powershell

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226741/mount-vhd-and-get-drive-letter) and this is not what I need. I want to be able to do it in two different steps.

```
# Mount it first.
Mount-VHD -Path $myPath

# Retrieve the drive letter.
$DriveLetter = *some code*
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If `Mount-VHD` or `Mount-VHD -PassThru` produce output then you can store it in a variable, `$foo = Mount-VHD ...` then you can simply follow Corey's answer from the link you provided, I presume. `$foo | Get-Disk | Get...`

Comment: You're actually right. You want to add this as an answer so I can mark it?